# Create colour-coded raster from timeseries of binary GeoTIFFs based on date of pixel change

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, time-series

I am studying seasonal snowmelt patterns and have a timeseries of 10 .tif images (one every 2 weeks) over my study area in which a pixel value of 1=water and 0=no water. I was wondering how I could create a single raster from these in which each pixel is colour coded based on its date of melt onset i.e. the date in the timeseries on which it first has a value of 1? I’ve given an example below of the sort of thing I mean. I've been struggling to find a solution in QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Is it safe to assume once a pixel becomes 1 because it has melted it remains as 1  throughout the rest of your series of rasters? I think some screen shots of your data would help.

Comment: @Hornbydd This isn't guaranteed as my data shows only surface water presence/absence on an ice sheet i.e. whether or not surface lakes are present, so water may have moved or refrozen in later rasters. I'm just looking for the first date in the raster series on which each pixel becomes 1, regardless of whether it becomes 0 again later on.

Comment: @Hornbydd Thanks for your comments, I've updated the post. I'm working in QGIS but am open to solutions in Matlab, python or within ArcGIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please decide which of the GIS products mentioned you want to ask about.  By asking about more than one you are effectively asking multiple questions which goes against the [Tour]. You should then describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, numpy can do this for you with a few lines of code.

```py
import numpy as np
import rioxarray as rxr

# Read the raster files
raster_1 = rxr.open_rasterio('file.tif')
...
raster_k = rxr.open_rasterio('file.tif')

# List your m x n rasters here.
# To check that you're using the correctly formatted raster data,
# Check that raster_1.data[0].shape is m x n
raster_list = [raster_1.data[0], ... raster_k.data[0]]

# Stack the rasters into an m x n x k numpy array
stack = np.dstack(raster_list)

# Find the first non-zero value along the stacking dimension
first_melt = (stack != 0).argmax(axis=2)

# If every raster has a zero in a specific position
# (i.e. the snow never melted), argmax will return zero
# We cannot distinguish this from the pixels where the snow
# melted in the first (0th) year, so we need to find those 
# and give them a special value:
never_melted = np.all(stack == 0, axis=2)
first_melt[never_melted] = -1   # Use whatever value makes sense
```

`first_melt` is now an m x n array of the index of the raster where the first melt appeared, and -1 if the location never melted. You can display it with

```py
plt.imshow(first_melt)
```

or similar.

Comment: Thanks! I've just tried this and got the error "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'argmax'". Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: hm, stack should be a numpy array, not a boolean. Edited my answer to show how to import the rasters properly.

Comment: Try printing out raster_1, raster_2, and stack to make sure they look reasonable to you. You can check their shape with raster_1.shape, stack.shape, etc.

Answer (score 3):

A solution is this:

You have 10 rasters where every cell has either a 1 or 0 value, so there are no nodata values. The raster represents a date, very two weeks.

I would recode each raster cells that equal 1 to an "index" value which represents the week, starting from 1.

So week 1 can stay as it is but week 2 all the 1 cells now become 2, for week 3 all the 1 cells become 3 and so on...

You can use a reclassify tool or a con tool in ArcGIS to recode your rasters.

So now you have a 10 rasters and for example raster 8 is your eighth week where the 1's are now all eight.

In all cases zero stays as zero.

Feed these rasters into the [Lowest Position](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/lowest-position.htm) tool and the output is your answer.
You'll need to deal with the scenario when the cell has remained zero through all 10 rasters. You could mask them out by summing the cells using the [Cell statistics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/cell-statistics.htm) tool and using the output of that to create a binary mask.